# How to POST REQUEST using JAVA REST API from application to another consecutively

Tags: java, rest, post, request, http-post

I want to send JSON data from A to D but passing from B and C and D will response through C and B to reach and response to A back. A,B,C,D represent as Application. Please see the Image below how i want it works.

[image: Illustration]

Comment: Assuming synchronous operation, each application will have its own flow to accept request, send it to underlying system, receive response and respond back to calling system.

Comment: Is there any example that i can refer to? im new to Java and i've search alot but unable to find related to this problem.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Enterprise Integration Patterns(EIP) to solve your issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate/ give an example?

Comment: You can use EIP tool like ApacheCamel, Spring Integration in Java.

Comment: Answer should consist with sample code/example and not just links